# What is the purpose of the authorization code in OAuth 2?

Tags: oauth, authorization, oauth2

Why do we need to ask the authorization server for the`Authorization code` and then exchange the `Authorization code` for an`Access token` on the same server? Why not to return an`Access token` directly, without issuing an`Authorization code`? 
I do understand that it is specified by the standard but there should be some logic behind this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OAuth - Why exchange the authcode for a token](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/67291/oauth-why-exchange-the-authcode-for-a-token) and, related, [Facebook OAuth 2.0 “code” and “token”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8666316/2096401) on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way the “authorization code grant type” is meant to be implemented is in a web app that has public and confidential clients. The `authorization code` is authorized by the resource owner and the browser (public client) redirects the application to the callback URL, passing the `authorization code` in the URL parameters. Because the browser is a public client we should not expose the `token` here. Instead, the (confidential) backend of our webapp, passes that `authorization code` as well as `client_secret` to the authorization server and exchanges it for the token.

Do you see how we protect the `token` and api `client_secret` by keeping that workflow in the backend?

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I understand why we pass `authorization code` instead of `access token`